# How can I get values from a csv file where some of the cells contain commas?

Tags: c#, excel, file, csv, xls

I have a script that imports a csv file and reads each line to update the corresponding item in Sitecore. It works for many of the products but the problem is for some products where certain cells in the row have commas in them (such as the product description).

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (UpdateFile.PostedFile != null)
    {
        var file = UpdateFile.PostedFile;

        // check if valid csv file

        message.InnerText = "Updating...";

        Sitecore.Context.SetActiveSite("backedbybayer");
        _database = Database.GetDatabase("master");
        SitecoreContext context = new SitecoreContext(_database);
        Item homeNode = context.GetHomeItem<Item>();


        var productsItems =
            homeNode.Axes.GetDescendants()
                .Where(
                    child =>
                        child.TemplateID == new ID(TemplateFactory.FindTemplateId<IProductDetailPageItem>()));

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.InputStream))
            {
                var firstLine = true;
                string currentLine;
                var productIdIndex = 0;
                var industryIdIndex = 0;
                var categoryIdIndex = 0;
                var pestIdIndex = 0;
                var titleIndex = 0;
                string title;
                string productId;
                string categoryIds;
                string industryIds;
                while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    var data = currentLine.Split(',').ToList();
                    if (firstLine)
                    {
                        // find index of the important columns
                        productIdIndex = data.IndexOf("ProductId");
                        industryIdIndex = data.IndexOf("PrimaryIndustryId");
                        categoryIdIndex = data.IndexOf("PrimaryCategoryId");
                        titleIndex = data.IndexOf("Title");
                        firstLine = false;
                        continue;
                    }

                    title = data[titleIndex];
                    productId = data[productIdIndex];
                    categoryIds = data[categoryIdIndex];
                    industryIds = data[industryIdIndex];

                    var products = productsItems.Where(x => x.DisplayName == title);
                    foreach (var product in products)
                    {
                        product.Editing.BeginEdit();
                        try
                        {
                            product.Fields["Product Id"].Value = productId;
                            product.Fields["Product Industry Ids"].Value = industryIds;
                            product.Fields["Category Ids"].Value = categoryIds;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            product.Editing.EndEdit();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // when done
            message.InnerText = "Complete";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message.InnerText = "Error reading file";
        }             
    }
}
```

The problem is that when a description field has commas, like "Product is an effective, preventative biofungicide," it gets split as well and throws off the index, so `categoryIds = data[8]` gets the wrong value.

The spreadsheet is data that is provided by our client, so I would rather not require the client to edit the file unless necessary. Is there a way I can handle this in my code? Is there a different way I can read the file that won't split everything by comma?

Comment: You say "imports an xls file".  Do you mean "imports a csv file"?  If you are trying to read CSV files, use a real CSV parser.  Googling should turn up several.  Parsing CSV correctly is not as simple as you might assume.

Comment: Simplest solution: Switch your delimiter to Semikolon **;**. Since your csv-sheet contains complex text, comma is not the best separator

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's a csv file but I could try importing an xls file instead.

Comment: As you read from exel file , you can import data with  all text columns with marks as double quote "" or [], and use these separators as  marks for start/end of string columns. You may need to modify your script to handle these separators.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use Ado.Net, If the field's data are inside quotes and it will parse it like a field and ignore any commas inside this..

Code Example:

```
static DataTable GetDataTableFromCsv(string path, bool isFirstRowHeader)
{
    string header = isFirstRowHeader ? "Yes" : "No";

    string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

    string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "]";

    using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
              @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly + 
              ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
    using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
    using(OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }
}
```